# Client side certificates in IIS for accessing a web app only from an specific PC

Tags: certificates, asp.net, iis

We have an ASP.NET web app running in IIS, with about 200 users, some are inside our LAN and other ones are outside our LAN. Every user has a userid account and a password to login.

Besides those credentials, we want to add more security for accessing that web app with this requirement:

> A user will access that web app only from its PC. If user goes to
>   other place and uses other PC, then he/she will not be able to access
>   that web app.

Our question is:

**IF**:

- A client-side certificate stored in the user's PC
- IIS is configured to accept client side certificates

**THEN:**

The user can access the web app only from that PC. If the user uses a different PC in which there is no client-side certificate, then user will not access web app.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the client-side certificate as a key. Wherever the key is installed, the client will be able to connect. At the opposite, wherever the key is **not** installed, the client will not be able to connect.

However, bear in mind that the client-side certificate is actually just a file a browser can import. It is not something hard-linked to a physical computer in any way. Therefore unless there are supplementary measures taken nothing prevents someone from importing their client certificate in several browsers running on different computers.

Comment: Thanks. What other supplementary measures should be taken for preventing importing a client certificate to different PC? Just asking for some ideas or a link to read more about it.

Comment: If the budget is there, I guess storing the Key secured with a TPM provides the properties you want.